# Buying Weapons in PvP

Tags: guild-wars-2

Sorry, I'm a total noob. I've read that there should be a PvP Weaponsmith and PvP Armorsmith vendors in the Mists, with all the items for free. I can't find those vendors, and I suspect there has since been a patch which removed those NPCs.

I *can* find how to change my build and everything else. Just can't find out how to change my weapons! Any help please? Sorry for such the easy question...

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the [wiki entry on Structured PvP](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Structured_PvP), you'll find that:

> Glory Vendors and PvP equipment were removed in the [April 15, 2014 game update](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Game_updates/2014-04-15).

This update removed separate PvP items and introduced the wardrobe instead. All you need to do in PvP is to equip *any* PvE weapon with your character and while you're in any PvP match, it will have the stats of its level 80 exotic equivalent. The sigils on it can be selected in the same PvP build panel (at top of screen while in Heart of the Mists) as your PvP traits and the amulet. See [the wiki entry for PvP Build](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/PvP_Build) for more.

Comment: Thanks @Amos. So, for example, I'll need to at least buy (or find) any old crude Hammer if I want to change my weapon for Warrior? I read your links (very helpful). So, it seems the defense on gear *does* carry over into PvP. Do you think this has any significant effect? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, that old hammer will effectively be "scaled up" to level 80 exotic level, just like a level 1 character gets scaled up to 80. If you equip a legendary weapon, it will be "scaled down", i.e. PvP is meant to be on an even playing field, even if one appears very plain and the other has a much more impressive skin. So your PvE armour and weapons are there pretty much to "provide the appearance".

Comment: I hope you could elaborate a little on the defense stat. It seems defense does carry over into pvp. Is defense an important stat?

Comment: Defense is the protection you get from your armour (and from your shield if you have one equipped, I think), and combines with your toughness attribute to reduce incoming damage. So yes, it's important, but like I said, the PvE armour you wear all gets scaled up to level 80 exotic stats, so your defense won't vary from one armour set to the next (toughness might, depending on which amulet you equip - the amulet has huge numbers on it which is equivalent to changing your entire armour set, I think). I hope that answers your question? :-) If not, go to PvP and play around with different armours.

Answer (score -1):

The vendors are in the place above Lionsarch.

Comment: Sorry, what's "the place above Lion's Arch"?